# MySql query between IN FIND_IN_SET

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have below data in my database table

```
id          activity          age_criteria
1           act1              18-25,26-39,40-59
2           act2              26-39,40-59
3           act3              40-59,60-79
4           act4              60-79
5           act5              18-25,60-79
```

Now we have search filter and there is only one text box that can enter one value at a time

like i am searching value "25" than i want 2 records(id 1,5) from above table. need below result.

```
id          activity          age_criteria
1           act1              18-25,26-39,40-59
5           act5              18-25,60-79
```

Please help me to resolve this with best way i am thinking with find_in_set and between with same query is it possible?

Comment: if it is 19 then the query should also return id 1 and 5?

Comment: you will have to use 18-25 as a value to search using find in set

Comment: I know its bad design of database but its made by someone else and now i can not change it somehow so is there any way to make that search result possible? @Bikash P

Comment: I'd suggest creating a (temporary) table with a better design, using the data from the old table. This not only helps to solve your problem, but also makes it easy to change the database in the (hopefully very near) future!

Comment: Yes @ A J. if it is 19 then the query should also return id 1 and 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` in combination with `REPLACE` if set of values are *in specific range* like `18-25` etc.

**Example:**

```
select required_fields
  from activity_age_relation
 where find_in_set( '25', replace( age_criteria, '-', ',' ) ) > 0
```

**Refer to Documentation**:

> - **[FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)**
>
>   - Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>       string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>       first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>       SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
>       Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.
>       Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work
>       properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

Comment: i can not use above logic because it will only check age which is exists in column like in column value is this "18-25,26-39,40-59" then it will check only "18,25,26,39,40,59" so if i will try to check "27" this will not give result.

Comment: Then the range set you stored will not help you. If you still want to continue with the same column design, you better write a stored procedure to get the result.